# problem in java program when runs in windows JRE

Tags: java, windows, string, unicode

Hi
I wrote a program in java.
in a part of program it extracts a string number from a web page and converts it to Integer.
This works in linux without problem.
In windows it works correctly when I run program from Netbeans's Run/Debug option;
But when i run it from windows and JRE it doesn't work! (It extracts that number incorrectly).
This is that part of code:

```
subcatPagesCount=0;
subcatPagesCount=Integer.parseInt(cutstring(CM.getResult(),"( صفحه 1 از "," )").trim());
lblPagesCount.setText(""+subcatPagesCount);
```

and "cutstring" method is:

```
private String cutstring(String in,String from,String to){
    int st=in.indexOf(from)+from.length();
    return in.substring(st,in.indexOf(to,st));
}
```

it Throws:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTM
L 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Typ
e" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><title>┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒ :: ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬
╪▒ ┘ê  ┘é╪╖╪╣╪º╪¬ - istgah.com </title><meta name="keywords" content=",istgah,╪º
█î╪│╪¬┌»╪º┘ç,┘å█î╪º╪▓┘à┘å╪»█î┘ç╪º , ╪ó┌»┘ç█î , ╪¬╪¿┘ä█î╪║╪º╪¬ , ╪º█î╪▒╪º┘å" /><m
eta name="description" content="┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒ :: ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒ ┘ê  ┘é╪╖╪╣╪
º╪¬ - istgah.com" /><base href="http://www.istgah.com/" /><link rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css" href="layout/templates/istblue/css/firev4.css" /><link rel="sty
lesheet" type="text/css" href="layout/templates/istblue/css/style2.css" /></head
><body>  <div style="width:980px; float:right; " dir="rtl" >    <div style="widt
h:213px; height:89px; float:right; " dir="rtl" >          <a href="http://www.is
tgah.com/" >        <img border="0" alt="istgah.com" width="213" height="39" ali
gn="top" src="layout/blue/hr_top_right.gif" />      <img border="0" alt="istgah.
com" width="187" height="50" align="top" src="layout/blue/hr_top_right2.gif" />
  </a>    <div style="display:none;">       <img border="0" alt="" width="0" hei
ght="0" align="top" src="layout/blue/hr_top_right_back.gif" />    </div>
</div>    <div align="right" style="width:767px; height:39px; float:left; backgr
ound-image:url(layout/blue/hr_top_right_back.gif); " dir="rtl" >
<div style="width:360px; float:right; padding-top:17px; " >               <a hre
f="http://www.istgah.com">╪╡┘?╪¡┘ç ╪º╪╡┘ä┘è</a> |                 <a href="http:
//www.istgah.com/province/">╪º╪│╪¬╪º┘å┘ç╪º</a> |                  <a href="http:
//www.istgah.com/advertise/">┘å╪│╪«┘ç ┘é╪»┘è┘à</a> |              <a href="http:
//www.istgah.com/user/">╪½╪¿╪¬ΓÇî┘å╪º┘à</a> |             <a href="http://www.is
tgah.com/contactus/">╪¬┘à╪º╪│ ╪¿╪º┘à╪º</a>              </div>          <div ali
gn="left" style="width:90px; float:right; padding-top:17px; " >           <font
color="blue" >  </font>         </div>          <div align="left" style="width:3
00px; float:right; padding-top:17px; " >                        ╪º┘à╪▒┘ê╪▓: ΓÇ¬┌
å┘ç╪º╪▒╪┤┘å╪¿┘ç╪î █▓█╡ ╪º╪│┘?┘å╪» █▒█│█╕█╣ΓÇ¼           </div>  </div>    <div a
lign="right" style="width:767px; height:50px; float:left; " dir="rtl" >
<div style="width:260px; float:right; padding-top:20px; " >               <form
action="http://www.istgah.com/search/ " method="get">                   ╪¼╪│╪¬╪¼
┘ê:                     <input name="stext" class="inputbox" size="25" />
                <input type="image" src="layout/go.gif" align="top" />
  </form>               </div>          <div style="width:500px; float:right; "
>                 <table border="0" width="500px" cellspacing="0" class="mc" dir
="rtl" >  <tr>    <td>    <a href="http://www.istgah.com/fireview/computer/">

.....

http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_3551/" > samsung</a> - <a href="http://www.is
tgah.com/firekeys/key_136241/" > ┘ç╪º╪▒╪» ╪º┌⌐╪│╪¬╪▒┘å╪º┘ä</a> - <a href="http:/
/www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_3066/" > ┘?╪▒┘ê╪┤ ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒</a> - <a href="h
ttp://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_1535/" > acer</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah
.com/firekeys/key_13206/" > ╪▒╪º█î╪¬╪▒</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/fire
keys/key_3100/" > ╪│╪º╪╣╪¬</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_625
08/" > ┘à┘ê╪»┘à adsl</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_3123/" >
╪╢╪¿╪╖</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_203/" > ┘à┘ê╪¿╪º█î┘ä</a
> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_1276/" > laptop</a> - <a href="h
ttp://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_7199/" > msi</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.
com/firekeys/key_2270/" > monitor</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/
key_321385/" > 5200</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_807/" > cd
</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_1870/" > ups</a> - <a href="h
ttp://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_927/" > ╪¬┘ä┘ê█î╪▓█î┘ê┘å</a> - <a href="http:/
/www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_2079/" > ┘à╪º╪»╪▒╪¿╪▒╪»</a> - <a href="http://www.i
stgah.com/firekeys/key_1723/" > sony</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/fireke
ys/key_532/" > ╪¿╪º╪▓█î</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_846/"
> cool disk</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_51650/" > ╪º┘ä ╪│█
î ╪»█î</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_51/" > ╪»┘ê╪▒╪¿█î┘å ╪»█
î╪¼█î╪¬╪º┘ä</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_13/" > ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘
ê╪¬╪▒</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_1766/" > ╪¿╪º╪¬╪▒█î</a>
- <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_3454/" > dell</a> - <a href="http:
//www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_12084/" > mp4</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com
/firekeys/key_3637/" > ram</a> - <a href="http://www.istgah.com/firekeys/key_381
0/" > ┌⌐╪º╪▒╪¬ ┌⌐┘╛┌å╪▒</a> -           <br />      </td></tr>            <tr><t
d align="center" >         <br />          <form action="http://www.istgah.com/s
earch/ " method="get">          <b>╪¼╪│╪¬╪¼┘ê┌»╪▒ ┘ç┘ê╪┤┘à┘å╪» ╪ó┌»┘ç█îΓÇî┘ç╪º█î
 ╪º█î╪│╪¬┌»╪º┘ç: </b>           <input name="stext" class="inputbox" size="30" /
>               <input type="image" src="layout/go.gif" align="top" />     </for
m>         <br />         </td></tr>    </table>          <div>         <table w
idth="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nls" >               <tr><td
class="ghd" colspan="3" >╪¬╪º╪▓┘çΓÇî┘ç╪º█î ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒ :: ┌⌐╪º┘à┘╛█î┘ê╪¬╪▒
┘ê  ┘é╪╖╪╣╪º╪¬ ( ╪╡┘?╪¡┘ç 1 ╪º╪▓ 84"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at istgahrobot.doscan$Scan.run(doscan.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What's the result of running it?

Comment: it throws exception "java.lang.NumberFormatException" that is beacuse "cutstring" extracted part of html page other than that number so "parseInt" can't parse it!

Comment: @Snigger - what are your `from` and `to` arguments?  And your `in` for good measure?

Comment: @justkt: in the question, `from` is `"( صفحه 1 از "`, and `to` is `" )"`.

Comment: @justkt - "from" and "to" are two Strings that my desired string is between them and "cutstring" extracts string between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not running the JRE with Unicode switched on. Try running your code with the `file.encoding` option:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Or set the [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`.

See [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) for more.

Comment: @Snigger - the fact that setting the `file.encoding` option changes the way your code runs implies other bugs to me. Check your code for uses of `InputStreamReader` where you don't specify a character encoding explicitly. Changing `file.encoding` is not supported and may introduce other problems: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515